# Find a HAL object based on /dev node path

Tags: python, dbus, hal

I'm using `python-dbus` to interface with HAL, and I need to find a device's UDI based on it's path in the `/dev` hierarchy.

So given a path such as `/dev/sdb`, I want to get a value back like `/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure python solution:

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
obj = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.Hal", "/org/freedesktop/Hal/Manager")
iface = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager")
print iface.FindDeviceStringMatch("block.device", "/dev/sda")
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with this error: DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.74" (uid=1000 pid=3181 comm="python /usr/bin/ipython ") interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager" member="FindDeviceStringMatch" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.77" (uid=0 pid=4111 comm="/usr/sbin/hald ")
Probably because I'm not the root.

Answer (score 1):

I would spawn a `hal-find-by-property` call from Python:

```
import subprocess
def get_UDI(path):
    cmd = 'hal-find-by-property --key block.device --string %s' % path
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = proc.communicate()
    # stdout
    return output[0].strip()

print get_UDI('/dev/sdb') # /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/xxxxxx
```